# How do you set a cookie in Puppetteer-Sharp?

Tags: c#, puppeteer-sharp

I am attempting to set a cookie in Puppetteer-Sharp, go to a page, and read the innerHtml of an element on the page, however, it appears that the cookie is never set.  How do I appropriately set a cookie in Puppetteer-Sharp?

```
public async Task<string> RenderPage(string baseUrl, string url, string cookieName, string cookieValue)
    {
      await new BrowserFetcher().DownloadAsync(BrowserFetcher.DefaultRevision);
      using (var browser = await Puppeteer.LaunchAsync(new LaunchOptions { Headless = false }))      
      {
        using (var page = await browser.NewPageAsync())
        {
          await page.SetCookieAsync(new CookieParam { 
            Name = cookieName, 
            Value = cookieValue, 
            Domain = baseUrl, 
            Url = baseUrl + url 
          });
          await page.GoToAsync(baseUrl + url);
          await page.WaitForSelectorAsync("table.summary-table");
          var cookies = await page.GetCookiesAsync(baseUrl + url);
          var element = await page.QuerySelectorAsync("html");
          var text = await (await element.GetPropertyAsync("innerHTML")).JsonValueAsync<string>();
          Console.WriteLine(text);
          return text;
        }
      }
    }
```

From the Chromium dev console, you can see that there are no cookies for the domain:
[image: no cookies]

From the visual studio debugger, you can see that Puppeteer thinks there are no cookies set on the page:

[image: no cookies on the page]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to be careful with your `domain` property. If it's not valid, it will be ignored.
For what I see there. You might be setting something like `http://www.yourdomain.com`, when `yourdomain.com` is expected.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to get the cookie to work by doing the following:

```
public async Task<string> RenderPage(string baseUrl, string url, string cookieName, string cookieValue)
    {
      await new BrowserFetcher().DownloadAsync(BrowserFetcher.DefaultRevision);
      using (var browser = await Puppeteer.LaunchAsync(new LaunchOptions { Headless = false }))      
      {
        using (var page = await browser.NewPageAsync())
        {
          await page.GoToAsync(baseUrl);
          await page.SetCookieAsync(new CookieParam { 
            Name = cookieName, 
            Value = cookieValue, 
          });
          await page.GoToAsync(baseUrl + url);
          await page.WaitForSelectorAsync("table.summary-table");
          var cookies = await page.GetCookiesAsync(baseUrl + url);
          var element = await page.QuerySelectorAsync("html");
          var text = await (await element.GetPropertyAsync("innerHTML")).JsonValueAsync<string>();
          Console.WriteLine(text);
          return text;
        }
      }
    }
```

Not sure why my code above did not work, though...